# Error 'Status Check' during Moodle installation

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, moodle

database > mysql (5.5.5-10.1.16-MariaDB) > version 5.5.31 is required and you are running 5.5.5.10.1.16

[Moodle Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n43Ze.png)

**My System's information**

- > OS = Windows 7 (64 bit)
- > xampp v3.2.2 (32 bit)
- > PHP Version 7.0.9
- > phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.6.4

I've been searching online, I found this link https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=330272 but it wasn't much helpful. What shall I do, Can I get help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the latest versions of XAMPP use MariaDB 10.1.16

Click on "whats included" here https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

So you will need to upgrade MariaDB manually. There are some notes here

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/upgrading-mariadb-on-windows/